# Testing a docker nginx container locally get this error

Tags: docker, nginx

A rails react app with nginx. Testing nginx locally with http://localhost I get 502 Bad Gateway in the browser.

The command line error is: 
How do I debug this?
thanks

```
➜  sitewire_web git:(docker_three) docker run --rm -p 80:80 --net sitewire_web_default sitewire_web_nginx
2020/06/03 04:51:16 [error] 9#9: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://23.217.138.110:3000/", host: "localhost"
2020/06/03 04:51:16 [error] 9#9: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://23.202.231.169:3000/", host: "localhost"
172.19.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2020:04:51:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.30 Safari/537.36"
172.19.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2020:04:51:17 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.30 Safari/537.36"
2020/06/03 04:51:17 [error] 9#9: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://sitewire_web204", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```